# Incremental database/table backup using pg_dump on CentOS7

Tags: backup, java, postgresql

I've googled how to take incremental backups (weekly or daily) using pg_dump on CentOS7. Some suggest WAL instead.

Can incremental backups be done with pg_dump?

I'm currently using pg_dump to back up the entire database. So I'd prefer to continue to use pg_dump to take an incremental backup.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Please try and ask 1 question at a time (otherwise your question will be closed at too broad).

Answer (score 0):

> Can incremental backups be done with pg_dump?

No. There's no support of any kind for incremental backup in `pg_dump`, nor is it feasible to add it.

If you want incremental backup you need WAL archiving and PITR.

There's some chance logical incremental backup might be added on top of the logical decoding facilities in 9.4+, but it won't be available before 9.6 at the soonest.

Comment: Thanks Craig Ringer for your immediate response. Good info on incremental backup.